# Apache mod_rewrite [R,C] not working

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have following setup

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/search.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^what=(.*)&where=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302]
```

With this setup everything is working as excepted

example.com/search.php?what=foo&where=bar

is rewritten to

example.com/foo/bar

But I also need to hit search.php again so I added

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/search.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^what=(.*)&where=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,C]
RewriteRule ^ /search.php?what=$1&where=$2 [L]
```

Now it 'skips' the redirect and its rewritten

from 
example.com/search.php?what=foo&where=bar 
to
example.com/search.php?what=foo&where=bar

Is the redirect not working with the C flag?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/search.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^what=(.*)&where=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,C]
RewriteRule ^ /search.php?what=$1&where=$2 [L]
```

For http://www.example.com/search.php?what=foo&where=bar, you cannot hit at the same time
/foo/bar and /search.php?what=foo&where=bar, Rewrite results only in a unique URL.

In the above rules, http://www.example.com/search.php?what=foo&where=bar, it will match all the 4 lines, at the last line, it gives /search.php?what=&where=, as $1 and $2 are empty.

So the solution is to remove the last line, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/search.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^what=(.*)&where=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302]
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not an option. I need to rewrite example.com/search.php?what=foo&where=bar to example.com/foo/bar but I want that example.com/foo/bar is rewritten to example.com/search.php?what=foo&where=bar